# Updating MVC application from ASP.NET 5 RC1 to ASP.NET Core RC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently updating my MVC application from ASP.NET 5 RC1 to ASP.NET Core RC2. I have updated my code to match the changes (no error messages at least) I am how ever getting a error when trying to run my application:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       {projectPath}\error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Users\Frey\Documents\bundlrs-mvc6\bundlrs MVC6\MVC6.deps.json' could not be found.  bundlrs MVC6    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  241
```

The code the error is referring to in the file is:

```
<Dnx
  RuntimeExe="$(SDKToolingExe)"
  Condition="'$(_DesignTimeHostBuild)' != 'true'"
  ProjectFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
  Arguments="$(_BuildArguments)"
  />
```

As Dnx is deprecated in ASP.NET core i guess i still need to change some project setting. After a few hours of googling my issue with absolutely no luck, i hope someone here will be able to help me out, or just point me in a direction :)

Comment: I spent a long time trying to get my converted project working as well.  I kept getting errors associated with dnx.  So I decided to make a new RC2 project and copy my code from the RC1 project.  All my errors went away.

Comment: make sure you delete the web.config from the wwwroot folder as it references dnx and in rc2 web.config should be in the root of the project. as Clint mentioned starting with a new solution/project helps make sure you get the right stuff and leave out legacy stuff

Comment: Try looking at this blog, https://wildermuth.com/2016/05/17/Converting-an-ASP-NET-Core-RC1-Project-to-RC2 explains whats involved in migrating to RC2.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I ended up moving everything to a new project as @ClintB suggested. If you write it as a answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have app.config in Web/API project remove it. Issue will get resolve. This is based on Github dotnet RC2 issue: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3419

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into an issue with `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.targets` and `line 241` when building/debugging a brand new .net core Web Api project.

Instead of trying to execute the application from Visual Studio, I ran `dotnet restore` and then `dotnet run` from he command line and everything started working correctly including building from Visual Studio and running the Web Api app via IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

For me the same issue has reproduced. I have solved this issue by avoiding the spaces given in the project name.

C:\Users\Frey\Documents\bundlrs-mvc6\bundlrs MVC6\MVC6.deps.json'

has to be changed to

C:\Users\Frey\Documents\bundlrs-mvc6\bundlrsMVC6\MVC6.deps.json'

it may solve your issue.